# what is the difference between "*pointer++" and "(*pointer)++"?

Tags: c, pointers, increment

In my program i have tried to increment pointer but i am not sure why that when i use *pointer++ it does nor seem to work and it returns 1 as the new value.
I tried using "*pointer++" in my program like you would use a pointer as an array
using `*pointer=*pointer+1`.
but it seems that when i use just "*pointer++" the value changes to one 
but when i use `(*pointer)++` it works .why?

```
Node=(node *)malloc(num*sizeof(node));
printf("%d",Node);
Node++;
printf("%d",Node);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*pointer++` dereferences the object and increases the `pointer` itself and after the sequence point it points (references) to the next object.

`(*pointer)++` dereferences the `pointer` and increases (after the sequence point) only the referenced object and leaves the `pointer` not changed